# How do I block the notification from a website asking if I would like to recieve notifications?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium to try to create a form autofiller for a website and I cannot seem to figure out how to block the website from asking to show notifications. Is it possible to block the website from asking this in selenium or should I try to click block?[Picture of what im trying to prevent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7hc1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your options object.

Where 1 represents Allowing the notification and 2 represents Blocking.

```
option.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

option = Options()
option.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options = option)
```